# Switch ... case prints only one list

Tags: c

I`m experimenting with linked list and trying to understand pointers better. Im trying to get data from file to linked list.
My file.txt looks like this:

```
&&&   
Carl  
18  
male   
&&&   
John    
22    
male    
&&&  
Jessica  
19   
female  
&&&    
Brandon   
33  
male  
&&&   
Ema   
23  
female
```

I want it to load to linked list properly. Also number of entries showed 1 entry and also it prints only once.

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DATABASE_FILE "./file.txt"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 255

struct info {
    char        name[50];
    char        age[99];
    char        sex[99];
    struct      info *next;
};
typedef struct info info_t;

void load_linked_array(info_t **head) {
    FILE *file;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int counter = 0, number_entries = 0;
    info_t *ptr = NULL, *current = NULL;
    file = fopen(DATABASE_FILE, "r");

    if (!file) { printf("Couldnt read data.!\n"); return; }

    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file) != NULL) {
        switch (counter++) {
        case 0:
            ptr = (info_t *)malloc(sizeof(info_t *));
            if (!ptr) {
                printf("Nepodarilo sa alokovat pamat!\n");
                return;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            strcpy(ptr->name, buffer);
            ptr->name[sizeof(ptr->name)-1] = '\0';
            break;
        case 2:
            strcpy(ptr->age, buffer);
            ptr->age[sizeof(ptr->age)-1] = '\0';
            break;
        case 3:
            strcpy(ptr->sex, buffer);
            ptr->sex[sizeof(ptr->sex)-1] = '\0';
            break;
        case 4:
            ptr->next = NULL;
            if (*head == NULL) {
                *head = ptr;
                current = ptr;
            } else {
                current->next = ptr;
                current = current->next;
            }
            number_entries++;
        }
    }
    printf("Loaded %d entries.\n", number_entries);
    fclose(file);
}

void print_linked_array(info_t **head) {
    if (!head) { return; }
    if (head != NULL) {
        info_t *ptr;
        ptr = *head;

        if (ptr != NULL) {
            printf("Name: %s", ptr->name);
            printf("Age: %s", ptr->age);
            printf("Sex: %s\n", ptr->sex);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried something with counter for example like this:

```c
        case 4:
            ptr->next = NULL;
            if (*head == NULL) {
                *head = ptr;
                current = ptr;
            } else {
                current->next = ptr;
                current = current->next;
            }
            number_entries++;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
```

It loaded 4 entries instead of 5 and also printed only once {here is my terminal}:

```
load     
Loaded 4 entries.     
print   
Name: Carl  
Age: 18   
Sex: male
```

Comment: `print_linked_array` doesn't loop, so it will only print one.

Comment: If `fopen` fails, it is not indicative of a read failure.  Rather than guessing at the error and making up an inaccurate error message, let the system tell you why `fopen` failed.  `perror(DATABASE_FILE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you never reset your counter. So after reading case 4 it looks for case 5, case 6, 7, 8.

---

Each entry has four lines, but you have *five* cases. The first entry will work, it will read its four lines, but then its `case 4` will read the next `&&&` and the next entry will be off by one.

```
&&&     0
name    1
age     2
sex     3
&&&     4
name    0 
age     1
sex     2
&&&     3
```

---

`*head` is only assigned to if it is null. If it isn't it is never assigned to and will not see any of the work.

---

You only allocate enough space for a pointer, you need to allocate the whole struct.

---

`print_linked_array` does not loop and will only ever print the first element.

---

With those fixed it should work. There's a few more problems.

- You don't check there's enough space to store the individual fields. Use [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) instead.
- The file is hard coded inside the function.
- This is not a good use of double pointers.
- Use the existing [`BUFSIZ`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// You can typedef and declare a struct in one statement.
typedef struct info {
    // Store pointers rather than arbitrary size strings.
    // Saves memory and allows any size fields.
    char*        name;
    char*        age;
    char*        sex;
    struct info* next;
} info_t;

// Have a function to consistently allocate and initiate your structs.
// Avoids reading garbage or walking off the end of the list.
// (Also have one to delete it and free its fields.)
info_t *info_new() {
    // Allocate the complete struct, not a pointer to the struct.
    info_t *info = malloc(sizeof(info_t));

    info->next = NULL;
    info->name = NULL;
    info->age = NULL;
    info->sex = NULL;

    return info;
}

// Pass in the file, do not hard code it.
// Return the new array. This is not a good use of a double pointer.
info_t *info_load(const char *file) {
    int counter = 0, number_entries = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if (!fp){
        // perror prints a decent error message with why it failed.
        perror(file);
    }

    // Store the head, keep the tail to work on.
    info_t *tail = NULL;
    info_t *head = NULL;

    // Use the existing BUFSIZ constant for your I/O buffers.
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFSIZ, fp) != NULL){
        switch(counter++){
        case 0:
            if( !tail ) {
                // First iteration, the tail is the head.
                tail = info_new();
                head = tail;
            }
            else {
                // Subsequent iterations, make a new tail and add it to the old tail.
                tail->next = info_new();
                tail = tail->next;
            }
            // We just added an entry, immediately increment the number of entries.
            number_entries++;

            break;
        case 1:
            // strdup() will allocate the correct amount of memory and copy the string.
            tail->name = strdup(buffer);
            break;
        case 2:
            tail->age = strdup(buffer);
            break;
        case 3:
            tail->sex = strdup(buffer);

            // Last field, reset the counter.
            counter = 0;
            break;
        default:
            // Put in a guard against walking off the case.
            fprintf(stderr, "should not reach the default case");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    printf("Loaded %d entries.\n", number_entries);
    fclose(fp);

    return head;
}

// No need for a double pointer to just read the list.
void info_print(info_t *head) {
    // Loop until you hit a null.
    for( info_t *info = head; info != NULL; info = info->next ) {
        printf("Name: %s", info->name);
        printf("Age: %s", info->age);
        printf("Sex: %s\n", info->sex);
    }
}

int main() {
    info_t *info = info_load("file.txt");
    info_print(info);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I made print_linked_array into loop, but now it wont print...

Comment: i exchanged if for while

Comment: THere's some more problems. Like you're only assigning to `*head` if `*head` is NULL. If `*head` is defined it is unchanged and will not see any work. Do you intend to append to an existing array?

Comment: And you're only allocating enough space for a pointer, you need to allocate space for the whole struct. `ptr = malloc(sizeof(info_t))`

Comment: @sccc444 I've added a full rework.

Comment: How do u free the linked list?

Comment: @sccc444 First you need to get the next item in the list, after you free the struct you can't safely access it again. Then free any allocated memory in the struct. Finally free the struct itself. `while( head != NULL ) { info_t *next = head->next; free(head->name); ... free(head); head = next; }` You can package the freeing into `info_free`. `while( head != NULL ) { info_t *next = head->next; info_free(head); head = next; }`

Answer (score 0):

There are some major problems in the code:

- `ptr = (info_t *)malloc(sizeof(info_t *));` allocates space for a pointer, not for the structure. You should write:

  ```
    ptr = (info_t *)malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
  ```

  This mistake causes undefined behavior, which you miraculously do not observe.
- `ptr->name[sizeof(ptr->name)-1] = '\0';` is useless if the string was shorter than the destination, and undefined behavior already happened otherwise.  Use this instead to strip the newline and copy the string safely:

  ```
    snprintf(ptr->name, sizeof(ptr->name), "%.*s",
             (int)strcspn(buffer, "\n"), buffer);
  ```
- you should get rid of the `case 4`: the new node should be linked directly after storing the `sex` member and `counter` must be reset to `0`. This causes 5 lines to be read for each element, corrupting the contents of the list.
- in `print_linked_array` you should use a `while` loop instead of `if (ptr != NULL)`. This causes at most one element to print.
- `print_linked_array` does not need to receive a double pointer, just pass the `head` pointer directly.
- `*head` is uninitialized in case of error and/or empty file.
- the file is not closed in case of allocation error.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DATABASE_FILE "./file.txt"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 255

struct info {
    char        name[50];
    char        age[99];
    char        sex[99];
    struct      info *next;
};

typedef struct info info_t;

void load_linked_array(info_t **head) {
    FILE *file;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int counter = 0, number_entries = 0;
    info_t *ptr = NULL, *current = NULL;
    file = fopen(DATABASE_FILE, "r");

    /* always set the head pointer for error and empty file cases */
    *head = NULL;

    if (!file) {
        printf("Couldnt read data.!\n");
        return;
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file) != NULL) {
        size_t len = strlen(buffer);
        if (len > 0 && buffer[len - 1] == '\n')
            buffer[--len] = '\0';
        switch (counter++) {
        case 0:
            ptr = (info_t *)malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
            if (!ptr) {
                printf("Nepodarilo sa alokovat pamat!\n");
                fclose(file);
                return;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            snprintf(ptr->name, sizeof(ptr->name), "%s", buffer);
            break;
        case 2:
            snprintf(ptr->age, sizeof(ptr->age), "%s", buffer);
            break;
        case 3:
            snprintf(ptr->sex, sizeof(ptr->sex), "%s", buffer);
            ptr->next = NULL;
            if (*head == NULL) {
                *head = ptr;
            } else {
                current = current->next = ptr;
            }
            current = ptr;
            number_entries++;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    if (counter != 0) {
        /* free partially filled node */
        free(ptr);
    }
    printf("Loaded %d entries.\n", number_entries);
    fclose(file);
}

void print_linked_array(const info_t *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("Name: %s", head->name);
        printf("Age: %s", head->age);
        printf("Sex: %s\n", head->sex);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```